# Should an auxiliary circulation pump be installed on the supply or the return?

Tags: boiler, radiator, pump

I'm adding a new 007 Circulator Pump for closed loop system. Problem is that one of the radiators on a third floor does not heat- tried purging air (it's a new added radiator). It gets hot when I continuously release air/water from return pipe, but it just doesn't seem like there is enough pressure to do it on its own. In the basement I have one 1" loop pipe and out of it 1/2" branches coming out to radiators. Correct way would be to use manifold, but it is financially not viable right now.

So I want to add new Taco ciculator pump just for that line (new radiator on the third floor since it doesn't have enough pressure). Do I mount the pump on return or supply? Which direction should the arrow point?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the existing 1 x 1 x 1/2inch tees. look closely; do they have arrows pointing along the 1 inch length? Do they have any markings letters or a name. If they do they may be  monoflo tees. Does the 1 inch pipe loop around the whole system or is it reduced as it gets further from the boiler. You need to answer all these questions to be able to identify the type of system you have. The new radiator you added, can you post a picture of it. Did you buy it new or is it an old rad. some rads can only be used on steam systems. If your system is a monoflo system then you need to install the same type tees to get the rad to work. do not add  another pump until you know what system you have. Re post and I can help.

Comment: If you do have a MONOFLO  heating system and you install the two "MONOFLO" tees required you will not need the taco pump you were going to install. Another thought is that a monoflo system allows you to have thermostatic control on each rad if you desire. Name brands I have used are Danfoss and Hineywell.

Comment: the water pressure in the heating system only holds up  the water to the rads. 1 pound pressure holds water up about 2 feet. It is not used to push the water around the heating system. The system pump moves the water, and the type of piping moves the water through the rads Post a comment if you have resolved your problem and gotten the rad to heat and how you fixed the problem.

Comment: Could you add a comment so everyone will know that the problem is fixed and how you fixed it.